# Use keyboard to control application menu in Mac OS X 10.6 or later

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to use the keyboard to control application menus in Mac OS 10.6 and later? I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> but it's not working for me. I am running OS X Lion.

Also is this acceptable use in OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to access the menu bar is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> if you have function keys disabled).

Type away the letters of the top menu items you want to access, and you're good to go.

Navigate with your arrow keys <kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> and press <kbd>↩</kbd> to activate entries.

---

But, in order to get to the application menu, there's another pretty handy keyboard shortcut. Look in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*.

[image]

This will focus your help menu, from where you can instantly search for menu entries.

[image]

This will significantly speed up accessing menu items by keyboard.

> Also is this acceptable use in OSX?

Why not? OS X has always been focused on using keyboard shortcuts, providing lots of possibilities for power users. Use them as often as you want. I do it all the time.